# PHP error reporting is of, but neither if and else check works

Tags: php, error-reporting

So, problem issue is:

Error reporting is not enabled in php.ini file, but when i developing something i use simple if and else checks. But as i was unable completely to even setup some session, i come down to basics, and wrote:

```
<?php

if (require_once('classes/sessionHandler.class.php')) {
    echo "file found";
}else{
    echo "file not found";
}
```

and i got message:

> file found

than i wrote:

```
<?php

if (require_once('abc')) {
    echo "file found";
}else{
    echo "file not found";
}
```

and i did not get anything, even file not found message.

What should be wrong in php setup?

PHP version:

> PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u5

OS:

> Kali linux 1.0.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because `require_once` throws a fatal error when executing the script, which stops the rest of the execution. You need to use `include_once` or `file_exists` functions instead.

```
$file = 'abc';

if(file_exists($file)) {
    require_once($file);
} else {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

It's better to have error_reporting set to on when developing. Thus setting `ini_set('display_errors', true)`

Comment: Even "better" than file_exists() is is_readable(). It's not because a file exists that you have permissions to read it. is_readable() confirms both.

Comment: i set your answer as best as that is way how i did it earlier. but since i was long time of from writing php i forgot, now you remembered me!!! thanks.

Comment: Stixx, that's not so polite to write the same answer 10 minutes after :/ . And I agree with Blizz, is_readable would have been a better answer

Comment: @Asenar, you know we are writing answers in favor for the asker, though there can be a situation were people write the same answer at the same time. So please don't blame me for not being rewarded, and only write useful comments.

Answer (score 2):

require(_once) generates a fatal error if the file is not found. If you always want output, try using include(_once) instead.

Comment: i got blank page with no contents again

Answer (score 1):

require_once() always returns 1 if file is found, and halts execution with a fatal error if file is not found. Hence you don´t see error output - your script died.

Use `include_once` instead.

Comment: i dont know how but you was right. beacause if(require_once 'file') is same as if(true) || if(false) it could not kill script for true and false values. what should i do to fix that? any idea?

Comment: oh yes, sorry i got it... i was away about year from php... but i got it what i did wrong...should use file_exists instead.

Comment: require and include actually don't always return 1. They only return that if you don't return something yourself. It is perfectly fine to do a "return FALSE;" and then the if (include(...)) will still "fail". It's just not common practice :)

Answer (score 1):

require or require_once usually falling with fatal error when file not found or not accessible for reading. In your case just simply turn on errors output and you will see your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow missing file, you have to use `include_once('file');` , that will generate a warning saying the file is missing, but this will not stop the script.

Or, you can just check if the file exists as follow:

```
<?php

$file = 'abc';
if (file_exists($file)) {
  echo "file found";
  require_once($file);
}else{
  echo "file not found";
}
```